# Large matrix algebra calculations in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, matrix

I am working on a project that involves doing calculations using large Matrices of data.  I have CSV files with 10,000 rows and 100 columns, and there are 10 of them.  Currently, I'm running a background job that reads the data from each CSV, pulls it into an array, runs some matrix multiplication calculations on the data, and then moves to the next CSV.  I'm sure there is a better way to do this because it seems like the majority of the time it takes to process the job is spent opening the CSV's.  My question really boils down to how I should store the data that is currently in those CSV files to easily access it and run the calculations in a more efficient way.  Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, I'd like to add that the matrix density is 100% and the numbers are all floats.

Comment: How big are your CSV files (as in MB, not rows/columns).

Comment: Are all of the cell values in the CSV numbers?

Comment: Have you considered storing the non-zero values in a database, each record being `row, col, value`? To operate on the matrix, have you looked at the [Matrix class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html)?  There are also some gems for matrix operations, such as [NMatrix](http://sciruby.com/nmatrix/).

Comment: The CSV's are about 12 mb each.  The values are all numbers.

Comment: And for the matrix operations, I'm using the Matrix class.  That works well.  I guess storing in the db is an option, although on Heroku that might require an expensive database plan given the multiple millions of rows this would require.

Comment: Roughly what percentage of the matrix elements are non-zero?

Comment: All of them.  It's a bunch of financial returns.  10,000 simulations of 100 years of data for 10 different portfolios.

Comment: That's helpful information, because it means it makes more sense to store all the values, without reference to rows and columns, rather than `row, col, value` for the non-zeros.  Values can then be retrieved with file pointer offsets.  You might want to do a small edit to say that the matrix density is 100% (and the values are all numbers [floats?]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSV is a very, *very* inefficiant format for any kind of large data. Given that all of your data is in numbers, and the fact that your data sizes are consistent, a compact binary format would be best. If you store your data as a binary file of 1,000,000 4 byte ints in network byte order, where the first hundred are the first row, second the second, and so on, it would cut your file size to ~8MB from 12MB, and completely remove the inefficiency of parsing CSV (which is really inefficient). To convert your data to this format, try running this Ruby code (I assume that data is a 2d array of your CSV):

```
newdat = data.flatten.map {|e| e.to_f}.pack("G*")
```

Then write newdat to a file as your new data:

```
f = File.open("data.dat", 'wb')
f.write(newdat)
f.close
```

To parse this data from a file:

```
data = File.open("data.dat", 'rb').read.unpack("G*").each_slice(100).to_a
```

This will set data to your matrix as a 2d array.

Note: I can't actually give you hard numbers for the efficiency of this, as I don't have any giant CSV files full of floats lying around. However, this should be much more efficient.

Comment: Looks like the data in the CSV is actually being stored as strings.  Is there a quick way to convert to floats before running the code you suggested?

Comment: Getting close.  THat worked but I get the following error: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x93" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8  when I try to write the newdat to a file

Comment: @dvanderb: You have to open the file in `'wb'` mode.

Comment: Even closer.  Now I get this when I try to parse: data = File.read("data.dat", 'rb').unpack("G*").each_slice(100).to_a
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40395/discussion-between-dvanderb-and-linuxios)

Comment: This is even easier with the [bindata gem](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata).  (You don't have to remember the pack/unpack codes.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [`Marshal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html) to save the array in binary?  I haven't used it, but it seems dead-simple:

```
FNAME = 'matrix4.mtx'
a = [2.3, 1.4, 6.7]

File.open(FNAME, 'wb') {|f| f.write(Marshal.dump(a))}
b = Marshal.load(File.binread(FNAME)) # => [2.3,1.4,6.7]
```

Of course, you'd have to read the entire array into memory, but the arrays don't seem that big by current standards.

Comment: Good suggestion. Marshal tends to be the fastest way to dump Ruby data out to file and read it back in. Not good if the data must be readable by non-Ruby tools, however.

Comment: This does seem to work as well.  I can't really tell which is faster (this or the accepted solution), but both seem to be fast enough for the purposes of my app.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could always load the files into an NMatrix and then save in the NMatrix binary format using `NMatrix#write`. NMatrix still needs a CSV reader and writer, but my guess is it'd be pretty simple to implement — or you could just request it in the [issue tracker](http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/issues).

```
x.write("mymatrix.binary")
```

and later:

```
y = NMatrix.read("mymatrix.binary")
# => NMatrix
```

It can handle both dense and sparse storage.